# How to Convert the string into array without using functions./ Not able to print last string

Tags: php

**Pardon me for the last question:)**

Here is my code to convert the string into array: it is not taking the last input in array, 
i am not able to find what went wrong. 
Code: `

```
        $mystring = "hi this is ram from Jammu";


        $array[] =Array();
        $string2 = "";
        $i=0;
        $j=0;

         while(isset ($mystring[$i])){

            if($mystring[$i]!== " "){

                $string2=$string2.$mystring[$i];
                $i++;

            }else{
                $array[$j]=$string2;
                $j++;
                $i++;
                $string2 ="";       
            }
        }

        foreach($array as $value)
        {

          echo "$value <br/>";

        }

  ?>
```

'
Output:

hi 
this 
is 
ram 
from

it is not printing Jammu .

If i add one more space at the end of Jammu then it is working fine.

Comment: It'd help if you tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use PHP's [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)? And it's because the last iteration of `i` falls true, thus `'else`' of inserting it into the array doesn't happen for it last word.

Comment: No, i don't want to use any built in function.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, i was able to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing `$string2` into `$array` only after encountering `" "` in original string. Since there is no space at the end of the string, you should check if `$string2` was filed with anything and push it to `$array` just outside `while` loop.